# How to resolve error while using instaloader?

Tags: python, instaloader

I'm just trying to login using the docs:

```
import instaloader
import pandas as pd

# Creating an instance of the Instaloader class
bot = instaloader.Instaloader()
bot.login(user="USERNAME", passwd="PASSWORD")
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mehdi/insta/insta.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot.login(user="USERNAME", passwd="PASSWORD")
  File "/home/mehdi/insta/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 634, in login
    self.context.login(user, passwd)
  File "/home/mehdi/insta/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instaloader/instaloadercontext.py", line 239, in login
    raise ConnectionException("Login: Checkpoint required. Point your browser to "
instaloader.exceptions.ConnectionException: Login: Checkpoint required. Point your browser to https://www.instagram.comhttps://www.instagram.com/challenge/<<HASH>> - follow the instructions, then retry.
```

The login info is correct
Maybe the problem is from the last traceback I see `https://www.instagram.comhttps://www.instagram.com/`

Answer (score 1):

Instagram is asking you to provide some verification code. You may use web browser to login to required account and do verification by hands. After that try to run instaloader again.